# A global templated extern variable without definition

Tags: c++, c++17

I am reviewing a large project that has a header file that is declaring a templated `extern` variable. Roughly speaking, there is a single header `foo.hpp` that looks like this:

```
#pragma once
#include <cstdio>

namespace bar {

template <bool ndebug>
struct Foo {
    template <typename T>
    Foo &operator<<(T &&t) {
        if constexpr (ndebug) {
            puts(t);
        } else {
            puts("debug");
        }
        return *this;
    }
};

extern Foo<true> global_foo;

}  // namespace bar
```

This header is included in multiple translation units and other headers.

The issue that I am struggling with is the extern declaration of the variable at the bottom:

```
extern Foo<true> global_foo;
```

I can not find an instance in the codebase where the variable `global_foo` is defined. Specifically, I am expecting to find a translation unit with the statement

```
Foo<true> global_foo;
```

but grepping the codebase reveals no such usage. Every usage is of the form

```
global_foo << something;
```

This suggests to me that `global_foo` is never defined.

Is there some special rule or scenario in which this is allowed?

The project involves building several libraries and then linking them into the main binary. I have tried deleting the build folder to make sure that there are no artifacts. I tried changing the libraries between static and shared. In every scenario, the project is building.

This suggests to me that there must be some rule I am not aware of, or some build feature being employed to allow this.

Comment: `Foo<true> global_foo;` is the definition, not instantiation. The linker should complain about missing symbols.

Comment: Right. And it is not.

Comment: ¿Is `global_foo` even used anywhere? If not then it does not need a definition. Also modern IDEs have handy features such as "Go to definition" or "Find Usages".

Comment: It is used in lots of places. It is printing out some info, and you clearly see that output when running the binary

Comment: I'm not a compiler person, but I what I mean is I don't think it's possible to produce an executable with missing symbols. You probably missed something. And that, we cannot help with.

Comment: In CLion, whenever I go to a spot where the variable is used (foo << something). If I right-click on foo -> Go to Definition, it brings me to the header definition. If I click Go to Declaration, then it also brings me to the exact same spot. This is bizarre

Comment: Maybe a detail that matters... The project is a CMake project involving CUDA, and is building all of the targets with commands such as CUDA_ADD_LIBRARY. So it is possible that there is something involved there which is performing some non-compliant behavior. In fact, this is the direct I am leaning.

Comment: Basically, I think that I need to make structural changes to the project to make a "true" instantiation of the global variable. But due to how this project is structured, that would be quite non-trivial. So I need to something "prove" that this is a compile/linker bug

Comment: My guess would be that the variable exists in a library for which you don't have the source. Could be the CUDA stuff, of course.

Comment: It's called the _definition_. Would you kindly stop misusing words so as to avoid confusion? In case of libraries, you can dump the symbols and check.

Comment: I think I fixed the mixup. I can't modify the comments any more

Comment: As for the external library possibility, that doesn't seem likely since the name is very strange.

Comment: suggestion: define it yourself and see if you get a multiple definition error (probably not because of template).

Comment: There is no error thrown. I went into one of the translation units that includes the header and uses the variable. The I add the definition to the top: `bar::Foo<true> bar::global_foo;`, and it compiles without error. I deleted the build folder and rebuild from scratch, and it still compiles without error.

Comment: My only other thought is that maybe this somehow is getting inlined and therefore not requiring a symbol? I really do not know what is going on here

Comment: For those wondering, I also changed the pragma to a header guard just in case, but there is no difference.

Comment: If you add your own instance to the code, the one (supposedly) in the library will be skipped. That's how libraries work - fulfill missing references.